# Setting up product purchase cost and selling cost in oscommerce

Tags: e-commerce, oscommerce, accounting

I'm setting up a **oscommerce** store for my friends. He gets a product at 48.3 INR and sells at 60 INR . TAX for product is is 12.5%
For this he wants to have proper system to calculate profit
Now when I'm trying to enter product cost in OSC, it has only 2 fields.

Gross and Net.

If I enter 48.3 in Net it shows 54.3375 INR in gross (*TAX). while I need to show 60 INR for that product and calculate profit. Can any one help me about how to this in oscommerce!!

I need to show product cost on product page as 60 INR. and I should be able to input purchase cost somewhere in OSC. So that its possible to calculate profit.

I'm not entirely getting whether its possible in OSC or how to achieve it.
Please help.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very possible. Either you will need to find a preexisting addon that does this or write your own addon. What you have described is simple to implement if you know php and mysql. If you don't then you should hire a programmer to do it for you.

Check out http://addons.oscommerce.com

Comment: Thank you for inspiring. I fired the same search query again and found these: http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/3161, http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/1594. I'm exploring possibilities now. These two addons might be my solutions.

Comment: Good.  Did either work out for you?  If nothing else you can use them as a starting point for your modifications.  If you get stuck with your mods then post it here and I'll help you if I can.  Please accept my answer if you found it useful.  Thanks.